# Illustrator graphic looks pixelated when scaled down

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I'm having problems in illustrator. When I scale my graphic down at 100% view it looks pixelated (especially the green lines).

Align to pixel grid is turned off and anti-aliased is turned on. Stroke scale is turned on.

I can't work out if it's because the lines are too small or not because it looks ok if I enlarge to a bigger size.

https://s12.postimg.org/3tbjydp1p/pixelated.png

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

1. Update Graphic Card driver's latest drivers,
2. maybe you've selected "View > Pixel Preview" that causes pixels. Uncheck it.

[image]